# I'm a US citizen and I reside in the UK, how do I get my Drivers License in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, driving-license

So I live in the UK with my British husband and I need to get my license, but I only have a passport?

Comment: Do you have a biometric residence card?

Comment: Are you looking to apply for a first UK driving (provisional/learners) license, or exchange your US license for a UK one, or something else?

Comment: Have you ever owned a driver's license anywhere or are you starting afresh?

Comment: Very valid question, but with so many queries above, I'm putting it on hold until clarified. Please edit your question with as much relevant info as you can, and we'll try and get it answered for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a driving permit issued by an EU member state, it's a matter of changing it for a British one and takes about two weeks.  There are no provisions to transfer an American driving permit because driving licenses in the US lie within the cognizance of the individual states and not the federal government. States are not allowed to make treaties, and it's not clear they would agree to reciprocate UK permits anyway.  You can always  double check if an exchange is permitted [here](https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence).

Permits are issued by the [The Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/driver-and-vehicle-licensing-agency) (DVLA), an agency within the [Ministry of Transport](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/department-for-transport), which in turn reports in to the [Home Office](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/home-office).

If you have a permit from a non-designate/non-member EU state, or if you have no permit at all, you start by obtaining a [provisional driving permit](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-provisional-driving-licence) from the [DVLA](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/driver-and-vehicle-licensing-agency).

Once you are up-to-speed on the driving rules, you can apply to take the [theory test](https://www.gov.uk/book-theory-test). Everyone must complete this step.

When your theory test is successful, you can then book a [practical exam](https://www.gov.uk/book-driving-test).  When this is successful, you will receive your [full UK driving permit](https://www.gov.uk/driving-licence-categories).

You did not mention your immigration status in the UK, I assume you are on a spouse visa, which means you qualify to take these three steps.  If you are in a different status, such as visitor, you will not be able to qualify.

Note: although it is not required, many people find it expedient to hire a driving instructor.